# Create a new object in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have some input parameters in my script:

```
Param(
    [int]$step=10,
    [string]$path,
    [string]$name
)
```

How can I use these input parameters to construct a PowerShell object?

Answer (score 2):

I am going to assume you are new to PowerShell. So I will demonstrate the most comprehensible way below (perhaps not the easiest in terms of how many lines of code it takes to write this):

```
$Obj = New-Object -TypeName psobject
Add-Member -InputObject $Obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Step -Value $Step
Add-Member -InputObject $Obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Path -Value $Path
Add-Member -InputObject $Obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $Name
```

There are easier ways to write this, but I figured this would be the least confusing.

`$obj` is your new object.